A specific program can't have their output being captured by TCL on windows whereas the linux version is working great
It's not the first time that I'm using TCL to capture output from a program executed by TCL. I did it several times.
the simple way is to store a result of the exec command in a tcl variable but it is not the good way if the ouput of the program is quite long or if the program wait a lot of time between each display.
so I use 2 other methods using "open" command. But none of them works with questa-lint windows executable (it is working with linux executable). :
method 1 (open without pipe) :
set appli [open "|toto.exe 2>@ $logfile" r]
fconfigure $appli -blocking false -buffering line -encoding utf-8

update

set update 0
set nb_ligne_vide 0

# Ecriture du rapport
set boucle 1
while {$boucle} {

    # Lecture ligne
    gets $appli line

    if {[eof $appli] == 1} {set boucle 0}
    # Si ligne complète...
    if {[fblocked $appli] != 1} {

        if { $line == "" } {
            incr nb_ligne_vide
        }

        if {$line != "" | ($nb_ligne_vide > 1)  } {
            puts $line
            incr update
            set nb_ligne_vide 0
        }
    }  else {
        after 10
        incr update
    }

    if { $update > 50 } {
        set update 0
        update
    }
}
close $appli

method 2 (open with pipe)
set appli [open "|toto.exe 2>@ $logfile" r+]
fconfigure $appli -blocking false -buffering line -encoding utf-8

fileevent $appli readable [list pipe_questalint $appli]

proc pipe_questalint { appli } {
    global done etat
    if { [eof $appli] } {
        close $appli
        set done 1
    } else {

        if {[gets $appli line] >= 0} {
            puts "TEST: $line"
        }
    }
}
vwait done

Using both method, I don't have any line displayed during program execution. Even if during the TCL program execution there is a windows command line displayed with all output generated by the tool executed by TCL.
If I launch the tool without tcl but using a command line in windows cmd.exe I can see ouput of the tool displayed in the same windows than the one I used to launch the program.
method2 (open + pipe) is working great under linux using the linux version of the same tool.
method 1 and 2 are working great also with other tool under linux and under windows. I don't know well the difference between both method, I don't know if one is better even if I guess that pipe method may be better optimized.
I also tested these code without the error redirection and I have the same problem. it is the first time that I meet this kind of problem whereas I did it successfully with more that 10 tools from different editors.
thanks a lot for your help

I'm wondering if you could try using the -translation flag to fconfigure? Maybe Windows is doing something.
Also, in method 2, maybe you should initialise the "done" variable to 0 after the call to global in pipe_questalint ?

setting done to 0 make no change. and this script is working great on linux or with other tools.
I played with fconfigure -translation option without success (binary, lf, crlf, cr, etc.)
I also added some messages in the script and the pipe procedure is not activated during the process execution (I can see log of the tool displayed in the command line windows but the TCL is still stuck in "wait done" and the pipe procedure is not launched. when the tool quit, then the pipe procedure is executed twice and the second time, the done variable is set to 1 without displaying any log (tool exit)

Ok. that's interesting you say "the pipe procedure is not launched" - this means the fileevent is never readable. What happens if instead of fileevent you call "gets $appli line"?
Also, maybe a stupid thing but are you sure you don't need the full Windows path to toto.exe?

I simplified the name of the tool. But I have the full path. The program is well executed by the way. The pipe procedure is launched anyway but at the end the tool execution... I will try gets $appli line...

i have simplified the code with :
set appli [open "|$cmd" r+]
fconfigure $appli -blocking false -buffering line -encoding utf-8
and then a lot of :
gets $appli line
puts "test: $line"
but it only display empty lines. I don't understand at all. could it be possible that the program execute don't generates output that could be captured by TCL ?

without TCL I tried  :
D:\app\iao\qverify.exe lot_of_options > test_normal.txt or
D:\app\iao\qverify.exe lot_of_options 3>&1 2>&1 > test.txt
and it works, I have the output redirected in the wanted file. so output seems to be correctly generated in the correct stream. it is really weird that I can't capture them with tcl

It might be that the call from Tcl to D:\app\iao\qverify.exe has some unusual behaviour. Does it even work from an "exec"? For example:
set exec_call [list D:\app\iao\qverify.exe lot_of_options  ]
set result [exec {*} $exec_call ]

I should have escaped those slashes in my last comment (but you knew that already!) :-)

The Windows version of the program might be writing to the console directly; there is a whole separate API for that. (This is a trick that Tcl knows and uses itself when it believes it is appropriate to do so.) The equivalent on Linux would be if the runtime decided to replace stdin and stdout with opening /dev/tty. It's hard to know for sure whether this is happening; there's a lot of complexity under the covers.
All that exec can really do is to make the pipes and hook the programs up to them. It can't force the programs to use those pipes.
You could try getting hold of Expect-for-Windows and using that to run the subprocess... That might work.

thanks for your answer, sorry but I don't understand what is your proposal "try getting hold and expect-for-windows" ? what does it mean ? for your information if I use redirection like > toto.txt, I'm able to redirect output of the program to a file so output of the program are kind of "well generated"

expect_for_windows seems to be a big stuff. As a workaround I can execute the tool and redirect all output in one file. do you have an example of TCL that would execute the tool and during its execution, the tcl will read the file that contain output and display lines after lines during the execution ?
